# Xamarin/Visual Studio 2017 app deploys successful, but no app shows in the android emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When I build and deploy my app in Xamarin/Visual Studio 2017, the build-output outputs the following:

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
1>------ Build started: Project: MedicineApp.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  MedicineApp.Droid -> C:\Users\Jon Ravn Nielsen\Source\Repos\MedicineApp_2.0\MedicineApp.Droid\bin\Debug\MedicineApp.Droid.dll
2>Starting deploy Android_Accelerated_Nougat ...
2>Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_Nougat ...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_Nougat -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_Nougat
2>emulator: ERROR: cmd_camera_device_start_capturing: Unable to set video format: 0
2>Hax is enabled
2>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
2>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
2>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
2>Emulator Android_Accelerated_Nougat is running.
2>Waiting for emulator to be ready...
2>Deploying Android_Accelerated_Nougat ...
2>Build started.
2>Project "MedicineApp.Droid.csproj" (Install target(s)):
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\Jon Ravn Nielsen\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\Jon Ravn Nielsen\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\com.xamarin.MedicineApp-Signed-Unaligned.apk "C:\Users\Jon Ravn Nielsen\Source\Repos\MedicineApp_2.0\MedicineApp.Droid\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.xamarin.MedicineApp.apk" androiddebugkey 
2>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-11-05) or after any future revocation date.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\Jon Ravn Nielsen\Source\Repos\MedicineApp_2.0\MedicineApp.Droid\bin\Debug\com.xamarin.MedicineApp-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.xamarin.MedicineApp-Signed.apk" 
2>Done building project "MedicineApp.Droid.csproj".
2>Build succeeded.
2>Deploy successfully on Android_Accelerated_Nougat
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The app seems to be build and deployed successfully, but the app does never show up anywhere on the android emulator?

When I first created the .Driod project, I could run the Hello World-app just fine.

Comment: run vs in admin mode then try it.

Comment: That didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: I could skype with you this weekend if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this just now by going to the Android Options, selecting Advanced Properties and adding x86 to the supported architectures. Then start the emulator from AVD Android Emulator Manager. After it starts, debug the app. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do I find the "Android Options" you mention?

When I first created the .Driod project in Visual Studio, I could run the Hello World-app just fine.

Comment: The Android Options are in the Properties for the project. You can right click on the project name in Solution Explorer and select properties at the bottom. You can also just right click the Properties in the project and select open.